# Joomla - need two separate categories of articles on the same page

Tags: joomla, categories, article

In Joomla 2.5, I want to display two separate blog-type streams of articles on the same page, with the complete text of each article. I can get one using `jdoc:include type="component"`. But I also need the articles from another category elsewhere on the same page in that same format -- first a category header, then the complete text of each article.

Modules I have tried:

- Latest News: displays a list of articles, not the complete article text.
- Article Category: same
- Newsflash: Displays the complete article text, but doesn't have a way to display a category header.

This seems like an obvious thing to want, but I don't see how to do it in Joomla. Is it just impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you want something ready-to-go, then this is your solution:

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/embed-a-include/18121 (Paid)

If you can modify joomla extensions, this ones could do the job (after playing for a while with the code to add the articles text to the queries):

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/13950 (Free plugin)
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing/7314 (Module)

Or maybe take a look at these JED sections to see if there is anything more useful:

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-listing
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/content-embed

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with displaying more than one category-blog on a home page, but have now found a working solution.

Install the Plugin "[Plugin Include Component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/8741)" and the Module "[Article Placed Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/content-embed/21939)" - both free.

For each blog that you want to appear on the same page:

- In Category Manager create a category to hold the blog items (articles).
- In Menu Manager create a menu item, probably on a hidden menu, of type Category Blog, referencing the category that you just created.
- In Article Manager create an article contaning just the plugin code
  {component url='index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=XX&Itemid=YYY'}, where XX is the category ID and YYY is the menu item ID of those you just created
- In Module Manager create a new module of type Articles Placed Anywhere, select the article just created and the position in which you want it to appear.

Comment: I could move my articles around with just the "Article Placed Anywhere" plugin, which is excellent. Thanks for pointing it out !